# reading strings from file and create a binary tree

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to read from file and create a binary tree?

My code is this but i get errors.

```
   public static BinaryTreeNode<String> readTree(String filename)  {        
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            return readTree(s);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not find file.");
        }
        return null;
    }

public static BinaryTreeNode<String> readTree(Scanner s) {

    String data = s.nextLine().trim(); //ERROR HERE

    BinaryTreeNode<String> left = readTree(s);
    BinaryTreeNode<String> right = readTree(s);
            BinaryTreeNode<String> root = new BinaryTreeNode<String>(data,left,right);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the error messages and input?

Comment: You've made no provision for dealing with the end of the file. For example, what happens if there is only one line in the file?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)

Comment: and my input is file like this Has feathers? 
Barnyard? 
chicken 
owl 
Is it a mammal? 
tiger 
rattlesnake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hasNextLine` to ensure the file contains at least one line

```
public BinaryTreeNode<String> readTree(Scanner scanner) {

    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        ...
        return new BinaryTreeNode<String>(data, left, right);
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("No data found to create a BinaryTreeNode");
}
```